# Thrift go support of map with struct value as key

Tags: serialization, go, thrift

I experimented golang generation with Thrift 0.9.1, for example,

thrift definition,

```
struct AppIdLeveledHashKeyTimeKeyHour {
    1: required i32 appId
    2: required LeveledHashKey leveledHashKey
    3: required TimeKeyHour timeKeyHour
}
typedef map<AppIdLeveledHashKeyTimeKeyHour, ...sth else...> EventSliceShardIdValue
```

in the generated code, EventSliceShardIdValue would be,

```
type EventSliceShardIdValue map[*AppIdLeveledHashKeyTimeKeyHour]EventSliceAppIdLeveledHashKeyTimeKeyHourValue
```

you can find the key part is a pointer which represents memory address. In golang a pointer as map key (instead of a value, or hash of the obj) is useless in most cases. To use a combination of some fields as map key, the definition should use a value type like

```
map[AppIdLeveledHashKeyTimeKeyHour]EventSliceAppIdLeveledHashKeyTimeKeyHourValue
```

Is it a problem of Thrift's go support (or I misused sth)? Any workaround to solve this problem in thrift?

Comment: That's a really good question. See also [THRIFT-2063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2063).

Comment: Thanks @JensG. It's really nice to use Thrift to define and maintain cross service/component data structure, however this problem make Thrift quite useless with Golang for this purpose.

Comment: Useless? Not quite. You just can't use `maps<>` with complex keys, all else is no problem. BTW, I still believe it must be possible somehow. I just had not that much time to dive into that. Ideas and quality patches are always welcome. ;-)

Comment: Well, it's surely useful that my company is heavily using it. just a bit blocking for my own project that tries to rely fully on thrift to build cross-lang core data. My wording was not accurate before. A quick idea may be generating 100% value type for all those struct been used as map key (including structs used as field), and pointer type for other struct. I have feeling that's possible. : )

Comment: As workaround, it's possible to dynamically convert struct to string in my code and define them as map key. a bit costly but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structs (without pointers) can only be used as map keys under certain limited circumstances (they must be comparable per http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators); it's possible that `AppIdLeveledHashKeyTimeKeyHour` doesn't fit this definition, so it's not actually possible to build a map without using a pointer for the key.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for the explanation. As I tried a bit more to simplify the key to meet those conditions, Thrift-go still generates pointer type as key, hmm.. have to check other solution.

Comment: @Evan: Correct so far. I discussed that stuff with some people, but I still think it must be made possible somehow, via some indirection, because  "*Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.*". So if the key type is wrapped into some container implementing a comparable interface, shouldn't that work?

Comment: Interfaces are only comparable if they have comparable dynamic values. See, for example, http://play.golang.org/p/E0kDtua92Y which causes a runtime panic because slices are not comparable.